# Share point site configurations issue while using port other than 80

Tags: sharepoint

I am using SharePoint 2019 on premise and hosting our .net application into it.

I created a site in share point using port 80 and i can deploy my application into it with no problem.

while creating multiple site to host the same application system is not allowing to host application other than 80

Error:-

error occurred in deployment step recycle IIS application pool the local sharepoint server is not available.Check the server is running and connected to the sahre point farm

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do some troubleshooting:

1. Clear the visual studio's cache.
2. Open VS as Administrator.
3. IIS reset executed before every deploy.
4. Use the account has full control and is the primary site collection administrator.
5. Restart the server.

Similar issue for reference: [Getting Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': A task was canceled when deploying custom action to Sharepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/861982/getting-error-occurred-in-deployment-step-39recycl.html)